# Why is my variable not being hoisted?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I have a global variable `i` which I increment (see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MvpXj/)):

```
(function increment() {
   i += 1;   
})();

i = 0;
```

​In Chrome, I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined`.

Shouldn't the variable `i` be hosted here, so that inside the function `increment`, the variable `i` is defined as `undefined`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variable declaration statements are hoisted. You have no declaration.

A declaration statement uses `var` to declare the variable. Since you haven't declared it, all you have is the assignment expression, which implicitly creates the global variable *at the time of the expression evaluation*.

In other words, no formal declaration means no hoisting.

---

Now let's say you *did* formally declare it, allowing the variable declaration to be hoisted. The operation inside the IIFE would result in `NaN`, but would be overwritten by the later assignment of `0`.

This is because *only the declaration is hoisted*, not the *assignment*.

```
// The 'var i' part below is actually happening up here.

(function increment() {
   i += 1;   // "i" is declared, but not assigned. Result is NaN
})();

var i = 0; // declaration was hoisted, but the assignment still happens here

console.log(i); // 0
```

Comment: Isn't the line `i = 0` a declaration and definition, all in one?

Comment: @Randomblue: It creates it, but it isn't a declaration statement. It's an assignment expression, which implicitly creates the variable at the time of the expression evaluation.

Comment: Doesn't `i=0` create the variable? I think the problem resides in the `i += 1`. It's equivalent to `i = i + i`, and you're trying to use `i` which isn't declared yet.

Comment: @MalSu: It would create it, except that the `i += 1` happens first, so the *ReferenceError* appears before it has a chance. If `var` was used to formally declare the `i` variable, then that declaration would be hoisted to the top of the function *(or global environment)*, and there would be no error even though the declaration came *after* the `i += 1`.

Comment: ...in other words, he knows the `i += 1` is used before the declaration, but is assuming the declaration would be hoisted, preventing the error. And he *would* be correct, except that with no formal declaration, there's no hoisting.